# rpmbuild fails on error: second %pre

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

when attempting to build a package using a spec file using the following command:

```
$ rpmbuild -ta foo-1.0.tar.gz
```

it fails with the following error:

```
rpmbuild error: second %pre
```

I see in the `~/rpmbuild/SPECS` directory that it puts the `foo.spec` in this directory as part of the package creation process.  What appears to be happening is it's duplicating the spec file entry in the file and causes duplicate entries.

My spec file only has one `%pre` and one `%post` entry.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: What version of rpm are you using? I don't see that error in the rpm 4.4.2.3 code. I see `second %prep` though (as well as `%build`, `%install`, `%clean`, and `%check`).

Comment: Same thing in the 4.8.0 code it looks like. Are you sure that's not `second %prep` and being wrapped or cut off somehow? Do you, by chance, have  two `%prep` sections?

Comment: no, there is a %pre and and %post ...there also is a %prep

Comment: If you run `rpmbuild -vvv -ta foo-1.0.tar.gz` do you get any more useful output?

Comment: $ rpmbuild -vvv -ta foo-1.0.tar.gz
error: line 415: second %prep

line 415 is the second instance of the second copy of the entire specfile that was put int ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/foo.spec

Comment: Ah. Each time you run the build it is appending an extra copy of the spec? Or just once? If you extract the file from the tarball manually it only has one copy of the contents?

Comment: nice find....the tarball put the specfile into the archive twice....why wtf knows...

I use the following command to generate the tar archive:

$ tar -cvf foo-1.0.tar --files-from=foo/.pkg_files

I generate the .pkg_files using find foo -print > foo/.pkg_files

but msax.spec is ONLY in the file once...  may be a tar bug perhaps??

Comment: Is there more to that `find` command? If not why would you not just use `tar -cvf foo-1.0.tar foo`? The spec file was actually in the tar twice? Not once with the content doubled? That's interesting (and I'd argue an rpm bug).

Comment: the reason I switched to using the --files-from method is that I have "stuff" in the application package dir (documentation tree mostly, images, etc.) that I don't want put in to the package.  Also, dot files were not being picked up and they are needed.

by removing the foo.spec from the .pkg_files file, it now works properly.

thx for your help...mucho appreciated :)

Comment: Removing `foo.spec` from `.pkg_files` still includes it in the tarball? What else is picking it up then?

Comment: the directory spec of foo I guess....this must trigger tar to read all files in the foo directory....foo.spec being one of them.

Comment: If `foo` is listed in `.pkg_files` then yes, that'll include every file in that directory (which was why I asked why you bother with the file in the first place).